# What was that xkcd strip, that show "Programmers don't need air"?

Tags: discussion, site-rec

XKCD quoting seems to be quite popular on the computer-related SEes. I am trying to find I strip. *There is a room of programmers, the deadline is in the morning, and a bird is dead in it's cage, due to lack of oxygen. Which is it?*

I am not sure where to put this question. There has to be SE for it, doesn't it?

Comment: required reading: **[Let’s Play The Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)**. As for "SE for it", this is definitely [SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Having a question to ask doesn't guarantee that there is an SE site where it can be asked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey And that's actually very sad!

Comment: @Marc: Why?  SE is not the Encyclopedia Magnus, nor has it ever claimed to be.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm sorry, don't take my too seriously. My comment was meant to be humorous. I just find it very nice that there exists a SE site for ~almost~ anything one can think of, and it's quite disappointing when you face an exception for this fact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nowhere on the Stack Exchange network where this would be On Topic.

Comment: Manga? Programmers? The workplace? <irony>I just want to illustrate to a colleague, that we don't need oxygen in order to work efficiently </irony>